# how to import models and handlers in webapp2 to ensure fast start-up of new app instance

Tags: python, google-app-engine, lazy-initialization, webapp2

I want my google app engine webapp2 app to start-up (create a new app instance) as quickly as possible. I was wondering what obvious slow downs I should watch out for (I know.. premature optimization, but I don't want to do a massive re-factor at the end if i can help it)

I have a folder hierarchy similar to this:

```
-root_folder
__init__.py
main.py
config.py
routes.py
models.py
gviz_api.py
... 20 more .py files
-web_folder
    __init__.py
    some_handlers.py
    more_handlers.py
    20 more.py files
    ..
-data_model_folder
    __init__.py
    some_models.py
    more_ndb_models.py
    10 more model files
-many more folders e.g. templates, simpleauth etc.
```

in main.py , I create an app instance with a router (the router is imported from routes.py). routes.py imports every single handler (assigning each route a handler). Every handler imports almost every datamodel. Will this mean my app is very slow to create a new app instance?

I'm expecting to have about 100 handlers and 30 data models by the end of my project, although many of them will be rarely used.

to import a data model (from inside some_handlers.py)

would just the following be fast enough:

`from root_folder.data_model_folder.more_ndb_models import special_model`

Should I be looking to use the config / registry ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, slowdowns are due to importing large frameworks, not large amount of application code. So I wouldn't worry too much about this, even if you have 100 .py files. (Trust me, 100 is not that much...) I'd also look into warmup requests.

I'm not a big fan of lazy import tricks -- they can cause complex failure modes in edge cases (i.e. hard to debug), and they don't benefit from the extra lenience App Engine gives to loading requests (check your logs for what it considers a loading request).

In particular, if you don't import all your model classes at the start, you run the risk of getting "No model class found for kind 'X'" errors.

Comment: It's beyond me how a "No model class found for kind 'X'" could ever occur - i'll consider not using lazy imports regardless. Everything else you mentioned was very helpful.

Comment: Also, by "large frameworks", do you mean any of the ones included with app engine? e.g. numpy etc

Comment: "No model class found for kind 'X'" might occur if you receive an encoded key from a user and retrieve it from the datastore. If the key's kind is X but the module defining class X hasn't been imported yet, you get this error, because the client code needs to have the class X in order to construct the result.By large frameworks I mostly meant Django; although the entirety of app engine also counts. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Webapp2 supports [lazily-imported handlers](http://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/routing.html#guide-routing-lazy-handlers).

Comment: Thanks, so is there any reason not to use these for every single route?

Also is my current method of importing special_model pythonic? each __init__.py file is empty.

Comment: I suppose I need to judge what's best. If a user visits handler1 and handler2, and both handler1 and handler2 import dbmodelx, then I'm importing dbmodelx twice. (whereas I could have put handler1 and handler2 in the same module, thereby only importing dbmodelx once).

Comment: Here's my guess answers to your questions: you should be fine using the lazy import handlers for all routes. I do in my apps. For your second question: I would use the solution that has less files. Local file access in app engine is not great (the java folks often bundle everything up into a jar file to do fewer file fetches). And I believe imports in python are cached, so importing twice isn't costly.

Comment: @robertking Only the first module to import something incurs the cost of loading and executing the imported module. Subsequent `import` invocations simply add a reference to the already loaded module to the global namespace.

Comment: Thanks, I thought something like this happened but just wanted to be sure :)

Comment: FWIW, link-only answers are generally discouraged because they can suffer from link-rot.  I've managed to hunt down a new link that works here, but you should probably update the answer to include the relevant information as well as the link...